# Is it possible to have a code for a YEAR+WEEKNUMBER from a start- and enddate in XSL1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file with not so much information it. I want to get the weeknumber out of an node which shows the date in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD

I want to have the following: YYYY"W"WW

W stands for weeknumber e.g. 2019W20

I tried some codes with substring from dates, but the only results I'm getting is the 2019M04 for example. So I'm getting year and the month. That is logical, cause there is no weeknumbers in the node I'm getting the result from. I don't know how to get the weeknumbers out of this.

```
<TimeInterval type="regular" billable="true">
<StartDateTime>2019-04-22T00:00:00Z</StartDateTime>
<EndDateTime>2019-04-28T00:00:00Z</EndDateTime>
<Duration>7.00</Duration>
<RateOrAmount currency="EUR" type="Hourly" multiplier="100.00">22.16</RateOrAmount>
<AdditionalData>
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderLineItem>0</PurchaseOrderLineItem>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</AdditionalData>
</TimeInterval>
```

I expect or I would gladly like to have a result 2019W17 because 22 april till 28th april is week 17

Comment: There are various [methods for numbering weeks in year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering). Please clarify which one you want to use.

Comment: Hi Michael, I want to get the weeknumber from the startdatetime and enddatetime (its always 1 week) and I want to get the result in number. So it start- and enddatetime is in week 18 --> result would be 2019W18 so YYYY"W" and then the result of the weeknumber. Is this even possible?

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: I want to use the simplest method.. I dont know which methods are avaible out there.. Thats why I asked the question

Comment: There is no simple method, only a correct one. The correct method is given by your business rules. If you don't know what numbering method your business uses, then find out before trying to implement it.

Comment: The numbering method we use is YYYY W and WW so in terms of result its 2019W18 . year first then the letter W and then the weeknumber

Comment: I am not asking about formatting. Please read the link in my first comment.

Comment: 52 previous year

Answer (score 1):

There is a template in the EXSLT date/time library that provides this functionality: see http://exslt.org/date/functions/week-in-year/date.week-in-year.template.xsl

To use this:

- copy the referenced stylesheet into a local file date.week-in-year.template.xsl
- add to your calling stylesheet `<xsl:include href="date.week-in-year.template.xsl"/>`
- invoke the conversion using:

code:

```
<xsl:variable name="week-number">
  <xsl:call-template name="date:week-in-year" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">
    <xsl:with-param name="date-time" select="$input"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

where `$input` is the supplied date-time in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Could you give me an idea how to make the result in your link work with the node? Im not so experienced with XSL, so I dont know what to do with the code in your link..

Comment: Added this information. But it sounds as if you're coding in XSLT before doing enough background reading: that's not an efficient use of your time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Michael. I'm not an programmer actually. Im an finance guy, but we use XML a lot and I'm interested in these things and I'm learning on the go. I did some coding work in the past but not so difficult as this one. I do know some things about it, but yeah Im not so good in it and I do search some things but impleminting a conversion or an file in an code is too difficult for me.. I'm trying as of speaking and I want to learn it but I'm only seeking help if i cant get  to do it.. like in this particular instance..

Comment: Good luck. But it's a bit like tackling plumbing or electrical work or bricklaying; if you try it from scratch and then ask the professionals for advice when you get stuck, they're going to suggest you don't attempt anything too ambitious.

Comment: The site above with the template doesnt seem to work with mine.. pff im giving up on this. Hopefully someone can explain this to me in dummy language lol